# Vuforia project coordinates to screen

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia

I try to project coordinates of target to screen's coordinates. I use https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/technical-how-can-i-project-target-point-screen with small fixes.

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/kcHbnzRy

Call function calcScreenCoordsOf in renderFrame

```
targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget] = imageTarget.getSize();
temp[0] = targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget].getData()[0] / 2.0f;
temp[1] = targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget].getData()[1] / 2.0f;
targetPositiveDimensions[currentTarget].setData(temp);

calcScreenCoordsOf(new float[]{temp[0], temp[1]}, trackableResult.getPose());
```

I recorded one small video to show results. https://youtu.be/k8qUT_72-PY

[image]

When I move the phone up and down everything is right, but when right-left red points move faster than the camera and completely ignored phone rotation